# How to read more than 32 message from Azure storage Queue

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, message-queue

I building solution to read message from Azure Storage Queue and pass the message to another API.
In API request body, i need to include as many message as possible in order to redduce no of api calls.

due to current limitation, I can able to read max of 32 to message at single read.

when I read next time, I still getting same 32 message from queue since i not deleted previous 32 message from my last call.

I can only delete this message after my API success.

Is any possible way to read more than 32 message in Azure storage queue.